# Angular2 and jQuery 'change' events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a hidden input to control the changes made by jQuery, which includes an event of angular2 `change`, like this

```
<input id='input1' hidden (change)='onChange($event)'>
```

Then in my case, I *have to* use jQuery to change value of this input, then trigger `change` event:

```
$('#input1').val('somevalue').trigger('change');
```

This `change` event that I triggered via jQuery only works with jQuery, but not Angular2:

```
//This is working
$('#input').change(function(){
  console.log('Change made');
})
```

In angular2 component:

```
//This is not working
onChange(): void{
  console.log('Change made');
}
```

How can I work around in this situation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could assign a template reference variable to the `<input>`, like `#hiddenInput1`, get a hold of its native element (via `@ViewChild`) inside the component class and then use jQuery itself to listen to the `change` event.

[**Demo plunker** here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eq1ghdNSUp5UHMQlTOgO?p=preview).

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <hr>
  <input id='input1' hidden #hiddenInput1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

  @ViewChild('hiddenInput1') hiddenInput1:ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.hiddenInput1.nativeElement).on('change', (e) => {
      console.log('Change made -- ngAfterViewInit');
      this.onChange(e);
    });
  }

  onChange(): void{
    console.log('Change made -- onChange');
  }

}
```

Comment: I've been searching for this solution for like 2 days. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good job! You saved my day bro.

Answer (score 18):

Angular2 change event is added via native `addEventListener`.

You cannot trigger a native event with jQuery's .trigger('change'). So you will need to [create a native event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) and [dispatch it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent):

```
 const customEvent = document.createEvent('Event');  
 customEvent.initEvent('change', true, true);
 $('#input1')[0].dispatchEvent(customEvent);
```

This way angular2 will fire `onChange` handler.

Here is a [**demo plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CCacgAvXnkbQLsXjgXEf?p=preview)

As @Cristal Embalagens mentioned in comments you need to use `input` event for angular2 because
`DefaultValueAccessor` is subscribing on this event:

```
@Directive({
  selector:
      'input:not([type=checkbox])[formControlName],textarea[formControlName],input:not([type=checkbox])[formControl],textarea[formControl],input:not([type=checkbox])[ngModel],textarea[ngModel],[ngDefaultControl]',
  host: {'(input)': 'onChange($event.target.value)', '(blur)': 'onTouched()'},
  providers: [DEFAULT_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DefaultValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
```

**[Some Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/iU6NiWfPrHUk4TXrK6gQ?p=preview)**

Comment: I'd say your solution works but @acdcjunior's answer seems to be the cleaner solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: For input fields use initEvent('input', true, true) to trigger the change event to angular2.

Comment: Thank you @CristalEmbalagens . Works! I wasted 5 hours because I didn't read your comment before :)

Comment: @yurzui perfect!  Your answer here was the key to my solving the problem of making Bootstrap events visible/observable from within Angular components.

Comment: @CristalEmbalagens Lifesaver! thanks for this awesome information!