# In Angular2, why doesn't form validation and change detection trigger when I programatically change the value of an input?

Tags: javascript, angular

If I have an `input`element and I with pure javascript would do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('myElement').value = 'Potato';
```

Then the form validation and change detection in Angular 2 wouldn't trigger. However, if I would have type that value in the input field, it triggers.

How can I setup my form validation and change detection in Angular 2 so that they trigger **no matter** how the input receives its text, whether it be by keyboard, pasting with a mouse, adding text programatically as the code above?

Comment: Did you try `dispatchEvent('input'`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557175/angular2-and-jquery-change-events/38560025#38560025