# ionic:Change event is not fired on <ion-input> when the input value is changed from external script

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to call the function whenever the input is changed.

I have created the following in my home.html file

```
<ion-input type="text" class="scoreboardus" [(ngModel)]='text' 
      (input)='onInputTime($event.target.value)' (change)='onChangeTime($event.target.value)'>
   </ion-input>
```

and in home.ts file

```
onChangeTime() {
  alert('onChangeTime called');
}

onInputTime() {
  alert('onInputTime called');
}
```

the above code works fine if manually give values in the input field.

My problem:

I am changing input value from one of external javascript file.

```
$('.scoreboardus input').val(200).trigger('onchange');
```

The above code change the input field value… But function is not called

resultant code should work after creating an app.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually

Answer (score 27):

The [Ionic's input events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v7/api/input#events) start with `ion`:

- `(ionChange)` instead of `(change)`
- `(ionInput)` instead of `(input)`

```html
<ion-input type="text" class="scoreboardus" [(ngModel)]='text'
  (ionInput)='onInputTime($event.target.value)'
  (ionChange)='onChangeTime($event.target.value)'>
```

Comment: @vSugumar since you're commenting the same for all answers and not replying to any comments, I will vote to close the question once the bounty period is over

Comment: @– i--  I tried all the posted answers before posting my question here...

Comment: You could try: this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.scoreboardus')
        .addEventListener('change', this.onChangeTime.bind(this));

Answer (score 6):

Have you installed the Jquery in your `ionic-2` as follows

Installing Jquery

```
 npm install jquery --save
```

After that, install JQuery global derectory to typings ( you can import it):

```
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

Then, you can import `JQuery` in your "home.ts"

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

Now try your `Jquery` function as follows:

```
$('.scoreboardus input').val(200).trigger('change');
```

**Update:**
You could assign a template reference variable to the , like #ionInput1, get a hold of its native element (via @ViewChild) inside the component class and then use jQuery itself to listen to the change event.

```
   import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
      <h1>Firing Jquery</h1>
      <hr>
     <ion-input type="text" class="scoreboardus" [(ngModel)]='text' 
      (input)='onInputTime($event.target.value)' (change)='onChangeTime($event.target.value)' #ionInput1>
   </ion-input>
      })
    export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {

      @ViewChild('ionInput1') ionInput1:ElementRef;

      ngAfterViewInit() {
        $(this.ionInput1.nativeElement).on('change', (e) => {
          console.log('Change made -- ngAfterViewInit');
          this.onChangeTime(e);
        });
      }

      onChangeTime(): void{
        console.log('Change made -- onChangeTime');
      }

    }
```

For More info Refer this [SO SOlution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557175/angular2-and-jquery-change-events)

Comment: $('.scoreboardus input').val(200).trigger('onchange'); actually changes the input field, but the event listener attached to it is not called...

Comment: @sugumar did you tried with `$('.scoreboardus input').val(200).change();`

Comment: you've updated or corrected the answer after seeing my answer. Though a +1 for the angular snippet

Comment: @i-- i have updated based on the link which i posted in my answer.. thanks for upvote

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to what you're looking for.

Your code has a small issue

```
$('.scoreboardus input').val(200).trigger('onchange');
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead of `onchange`, you should use `change` to trigger the action. `on` should not be added as prefix. The event name should be the same we are using in `on()` function in jQuery or `addEventListener` in JavaScript.

```
$('.scoreboardus input').val(200).trigger('change');
```

`onchange` won't work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ip').on('change',function(){
    alert(this.value);
  });
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#ip').val('test').trigger('onchange');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ip" />
<button id="btn">Change</button>
```

you have to use `change` instead

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ip').on('change',function(){
    alert(this.value);
  });
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#ip').val('test').trigger('change');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ip" />
<button id="btn">Change</button>
```

Your code works only when editing manually is because the changes made by the scripts won't trigger the event listener. You have to trigger it manually.

Also note that you have to use arrow function `()=>{}` inside Angular and add the jQuery code inside `ngAfterViewInit` then only dynamic elements will be supported in angular

Comment: can you add the angular code you tried? not working means is it set the value and not trigger the event or not setting the value at all?

Answer (score 2):

There are two dark points in your way, what we can not control. They are:
1. `(change)='onChangeTime($event.target.value)'`. I'm not sure how Ionic bind `change` function. Maybe it is not the same with `change` function of `input`. So we can not control it.
2. `$(...).trigger('onchange')` we can not control how Jquery triggle it.

So, just do the way that **we know and we can control**. It is pure javascript.

```
<ion-input type="text" class="scoreboardus" [(ngModel)]='text'> </ion-input>
```

You should add `onChange` listener by javascript:

```
ionViewDidEnter() { 
    let input = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('.scoreboardus input');
    input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      console.log("onChange function fired");
      //Your onChange function here. Do what you want
      this.text = event.target["value"];
    })

    //Now we try to change your input value by javascript
    setTimeout(() => {
      input.value = "Hey. Im changing";

      //Trigger onChange function manually
      var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
      evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
      input.dispatchEvent(evt);
      console.log("I'm done");
    }, 3000)
  }
```

Comment: Don't do this. If you're using "addEventListener" in angular you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Lenny : :"If you're using "addEventListener" in angular you're doing something wrong". Can you please explain that?

Comment: The whole point of a framework like angular is so you don't have to manually manipulate the DOM. In fact, manually bypassing angular can cause very unpredictable bugs. Plus, is usually way more work than just doing it "The Angular Way"

Comment: @Lenny I agree that angular help us don't have to manually manipulate the DOM. But Angular can not support us in all cases. This case is an example. We need to manipulate DOM by pure JS to achive what we want. I often do that and  did not find any downside of it

Comment: Angular has built in change detection so this isn't needed, HOWEVER in a scenario where you do need to manually bind to the DOM you still shouldn't use vanilla JS as angular has decorators for this. See: `@HostListener()` and `@HostBinding()` in the angular docs

Answer (score 0):

Use keyup event this fires event handlers automatically and works for me

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="nickname" (keypress)="onChange($event)" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```